# How to Apply SlimScroll to Body Element?

Tags: jquery-plugins, element, scroller, slimscroll

So I've been trying to apply the plugin to the Body Element and for some reason it just doesn't work.. 
Things I've tried:

```
$(function() {
  $('body, html').slimScroll({
    size: '8px',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    color: '#ff4800',
    allowPageScroll: true,
    alwaysVisible: true
  });
});

$(function() {
  $('#body').slimScroll({
    size: '8px',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    color: '#ff4800',
    allowPageScroll: true,
    alwaysVisible: true
  });
});
```

Does anyone know what Im doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance for answering

"What If I dont have control of the body tag ? and Im embed a template into a 3rd party site? so the body has no id tag it only has  view-source:avatars.imvu.com/LadyKonstantine"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you need to apply slim scroll on body you have to use the body selector for jQuery. The code will be like this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("body").slimScroll({
          size: '8px', 
          width: '100%', 
          height: '100%', 
          color: '#ff4800', 
          allowPageScroll: true, 
          alwaysVisible: true     
        });
      });
    </script>
```

**Remember these**

- Make sure you have installed both jQuery and slimScroll plugin.
- Scroll will be visible if your body have height above 100%
- If you would like to use $("#body") instead of $("body") don't forget to add

  ```
  <body id="body">
  ```

**More Details**

Click [here](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/)! to read more about slim scroll.

Comment: What If I dont have control of the body tag ? and Im embed a template into a 3rd party site? so the body has no id tag it only has <body> view-source:http://avatars.imvu.com/LadyKonstantine

Comment: You can simply use $("body") if you don't have any id or class.

Comment: Chris, please check this if you have any doubt http://jsfiddle.net/mijoemathew/59pmV/ and mark my answer useful :)

Comment: Thanks bro! this really helped me! :)

Answer (score 5):

Attaching slimScroll directly to Body tag is not a preffered solution in my view. Try it and you will find the slimScroll wraps your  BODY tag inside it's own DIV tag; at least I found it that way when I attempted to attached slimScroll to the BODY element. As a result, you will find the HTML of your page is a complete mess. The sequence of tags will be `HEAD - slimScrollDiv - BODY`. Instead, I suggest to have a wrapper DIV inside BODY immediately after you open BODY tag and then attach slimScroll to this wrapper DIV.

Answer (score 2):

SlimScroll only works on div element. To achieve this, add a main wrapper just after the opening body tag. In this case I will call it:

In the HTML:

```
<div id="body"></div>
```

Then calculate the viewport height, not the HTML, document height. Once done, pass this value to the height of the slimscroll plugin. Example:

In the JS:

```
var viewportHeight= $(window).height();
$('#body').slimScroll({
    height: viewportHeight+'px',
    color: '#455A64',
    distance: '0',
    allowPageScroll: true, 
    alwaysVisible: true     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the new CSS value of vh to compute the height of slimscroll. Example:

```
$('#body').slimScroll({
    height: '100vh',
    color: '#455A64',
    distance: '0',
    allowPageScroll: true, 
    alwaysVisible: true     
});
```